# Entity Framework: How to set up new database connection and run all migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have developed a WPF app with a local SQL Server database using Entity Framework code-first.

After replacing my old connection string with the new one in `app.config`, how do I run all migrations to the new, remote database?

Do I need to change anything with the Entity Framework tag in `app.config`?

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

To make it clearer: my problem is that now if I run `Update-Database`, I expect it to run all migrations that it doesn't find on the newly defined database server, which should be all as none exist yet on that new server. Instead, what I get is:

```
PM> Update-Database
No pending explicit migrations.
```

So it still looks at the old database even though I replaced the connection string.

Comment: Local or remote, it is no different. What problem are you having?

Comment: I'll make my question more clear. My problem is EF not recognizing (or migrating to) the new connection after replacing the connection string.

Comment: Assuming you are using the powershell technique, what happens when you run `Update-Database` ?

Comment: Added that info to my Post

Comment: I have a feeling you are still connected to the first database. If you run your application does it break with a SqlException or does it work and do you see updates in the first database?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't break. Now I don't know why it still uses the old, commented-out connection :S

Comment: Do I need to use the powershell/console to set up the new connection?

Comment: No, that is just to run the migration commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue myself. The way I initially declared my DbContext class and constructor was as follows:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext : base() 
    { }
}
```

Apparently, EntityFramework automatically finds the connection string from `app.config`. But when I changed that connection string, even though I did not change its name, EF didn't apply that change by itself. So I changed the constructor to

```
    public MyContext : base("mycn") // unchanged name of the connection string
    { }
```

Only then did it apply the change. A bit weird to me but eh...